# How can I read the number of received TCP segments for a socket

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, ip

I have an active TCP connection in a user-mode application that has no root privileges. I was wondering if there would be a way to programmatically check what is the number of TCP segments or the size of TCP/IP headers that the other side has sent me. I know there is no portable way, but perhaps the Linux kernel offers this information? Does anybody know?

Comment: How is this related to `C`?

Comment: Well the Linux kernel interfaces are usually available in C but you are right that the programming language doesn't really matter.

Comment: For what purpose? This is a very unusual requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with this. TCP is a byte stream and not a message based protocol so the actual segments don't matter at all. The same data can be packetized differently for transport, i.e. different number of segments, different size etc and they are still the same data. And what do you want with *".. the size of TCP/IP headers"* - IP+TCP header has a fixed size with IPv4 and has usually a constant size with IPv6 too. I have the feeling that this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Well I have a server, so I need to allow each client to send a certain amount of traffic. The byte stream is one thing, but there is a very big difference between someone sending, say, 1400 bytes in one packet and sending one byte per packet because, as you pointed out, TCP/IP headers have a fixed size, whereas packets (TCP segments) have a variable size.

Comment: Yes there is a difference, but there is nothing you can do about it at the receiving end. You haven't really answered the question. NB TCP headers do not have a fixed size.

Comment: Thought the purpose was pretty clear - traffic monitoring and shaping for these TCP connections.

Ok so TCP headers have no fixed size, but they do have a minimum size, which makes it even worse.

Of course I can do something about it at the receiving end. I could disconnect the socket and stop accepting connections from that user, or even close the port, so I won't receive connections from any user. And from then on, they could only send SYN packets. I assume the upstream router would block them at some point in case it is a DoS attack.

Comment: But why do you care about header length or segment count? You have the actual number of bytes being received. That's al you need.

Comment: As far as I know the kernel will only gather per protocol (as opposed to per socket) info. Have a look in /proc/net/tcp, /proc/net/snmp for example. As mentioned by others, there´s little you can do with that information (unless you have control over the sending app and can force it to burst data in larger chunks).

Comment: Thanks but I need it per connection. If I am not mistaken, one can gather such information using things like 'iptables' or 'netfilter'. So obviously the data must be useful in some ways. My question was only whether it would be possible to do read this information for my own process without root privileges.